# Freeradius: Session Timeout attribute for one time login

Tags: freeradius

I have Mikrotik and External Freeradius. Radius user are working fine, But the problem is radius user are able to authenticate multiple times. We want to allow him one time use, if he trying same credentials second time radius should not allow him. and I have checked attributes Session-Timeout also, but user are able to relogin.

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways to accomplish this.. but all of them require custom logic implementation, may be using Unlang or any programming language you know. Assuming you're using Database for storing user credentials, The simplest solution would be having a boolean column set to false by default, and as the user logs in just change it to true. and add this as a check when user tries to login. reject if the boolean is already set to true.